# Return max value array based on previous values

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have a dataframe `df` with a column titled `Price` as follows:

```
Price
 3    
 2    
12    
 5
 7
16
```

How to find the maximum values in a list based on lower indices? For the above data, I am expecting the output as `3, 12, 16`. Of course, we can do this easily using a `for` loop but how to achieve this without using `for` loop?

Comment: If you're expecting results based on the "lower indices", including the index in the question would be helpful?

Comment: How about `df.cummax().drop_duplicates()`?

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem That helped. Thanks!